# I can't access any programs on my Win 7 computer because of a virus: solution?

Tags: windows-7, virus

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Computer is infected by a virus or a malware, what do I do now?](https://superuser.com/questions/100360/computer-is-infected-by-a-virus-or-a-malware-what-do-i-do-now)

I don't have direct access to the problem computer.  It's in fact my mother's computer but she doesn't want to take it in to a shop or use a call-in tech guy so I'd thought I'd ask all of you for any tips or instructions I can tell my mum to follow.

The cause and issue: she clicked on a web link and since then she said a program is always on the screen asking her to "scan" for a virus.  Kaspersky Internet Suite is installed on the computer but the virus doesn't let her open it.  She says she can't use "System Restore" or even open Excel or IE.  Nothing works.  Is there a way to delete the virus by somehow running Kaspersky?  I think the anti-virus program has a "safe mode" part if that helps any...so is there any way to save this computer? Tips?  Suggestions?

Please give step-by-step instructions.  Thanks.

Win 7 Pro.

Comment: Take a look at the duplicate link. You need to give us a reason to reopen this.

Comment: @studiohack Please reopen this question. I have changed the focus of the question. It's not as general as the linked one. I want to know more specifics about my particular situation than just "got a virus" etcetera. Thanks.

Comment: @SimonSheehan  I have looked at the duplicate link but it's too general.  I really do want to know how serious this virus is + I'm in need a much more tailored answer to my problem.  I have revised my post.

Comment: I edited it my post but now it has gone back to the old version!!  I spent so much time...

Comment: @verve in its current state, it is still a duplicate...

Comment: @studiohack  But someone rolled back my new post back to the old one.  Please post my new edit.

Comment: @verve even with your previous edits, the question would still get closed.  If not a duplicate, then as 'too localized'.

Comment: The whole point of a "general answer" post is that we don't need a troubleshooting question for every virus infection there is. Tell us what you tried from those steps mentioned, especially with a Live CD.., but, as an honest tip: Do yourself a favor and reinstall!